# notifyDataSetChanged not updating RecyclerView although ArrayList reference is not lost

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I appreciate that this question has been asked MANY times in SO but all the solutions refer to a missing reference in my arraylist which currently I (believe) am preserving.

I have an adapter as follows:

```
/**
 * [RecyclerView.Adapter] that can display a [Note].
 */
class MyNoteRecyclerViewAdapter(
    private var notes: ArrayList<Note>,
    private val onNoteSelectedListener: MainActivityContract.OnNoteSelectedListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyNoteRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private val mNotes: ArrayList<Note> = notes

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes_list, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = mNotes[position]
        holder.bind(item, onNoteSelectedListener)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = mNotes.size

    fun setItems(notes: ArrayList<Note>) {
        mNotes.clear()
        mNotes.addAll(notes)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        private val idView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.item_number)
        private val contentView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.content)

        fun bind(item: Note, onNoteSelectedListener: MainActivityContract.OnNoteSelectedListener) {
            idView.text = item.id
            contentView.text = item.title
            itemView.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { onNoteSelectedListener.onNoteSelected(item) })
        }

        override fun toString(): String {
            return super.toString() + " '" + contentView.text + "'"
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see above, the function setItems() is setting clearing all notes in the list and readding them followed by notifyDataSetChanged()

The view that calls this is here:

```
class NotesListFragment() : BaseFragment(), MainActivityContract.OnNoteSelectedListener {

    var mAdapter: MyNoteRecyclerViewAdapter? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes_list_list, container, false)
        val lvNotes = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.lv_notes);

        mAdapter = MyNoteRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Note>(), this)
        lvNotes.adapter = mAdapter

        return view
    }

    override fun onNoteSelected(note: Note) {
        (activity as MainActivity).onNoteSelected(Note());
    }

    fun onNotesLoaded(notes: ArrayList<Note>) {
        mAdapter?.setItems(notes)
        view?.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.lv_notes)?.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}
```

The function onNotesLoaded is called by an external class that fetches notes. As you can see, I am setting items using mAdapter.setItems() which should notify the list that data has changed but without luck. I tried to also add the second line to see if it's something I'm missing but again, no luck.

I'm not sure if this is a kotlin issue on my part when assigning the list variable but any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the list being displayed at any given time

Comment: @EvansChepsiror Yes, if I minimize the app and reopen it, the list displays correctly

Comment: I am curious to know the source of your data. Are you using live data?

Comment: @EvansChepsiror No, I'm currently just looping 20 times and populating 20 items, and I added a Thread.sleep(3000) as a test for slow networks

Comment: @EvansChepsiror But having said that, it seems like the issue gets fixed if I remove Thread.sleep

Comment: Why do you need to have a Thread.sleep?

Answer (score 0):

It seem you forgot add `LayoutManager` for `RecyclerView`

```
mAdapter = MyNoteRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Note>(), this)
lvNotes.adapter = mAdapter
lvNotes.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue lied in other areas of my codebase so I will close this question. Thanks for anyone who tried to help